# Git head detached from branch

Tags: git

I have been working on GIT. I had some issues so by R-n-D I picked some head. I kept on working for long. I commit my code. When I checked in console it showed me your head is pointing at `a6dd3dd`.

I checkout to origin master, and it showed head detached from `this.n.this` And everything gone up. Though I commit in my last head. How would I move to that head again. And push my code to Origin master so my whole code get merge. Would my code done at that head is safe?? How can I retrieve it back and mix with current code in master.

Comment: I am still not clear for the reason of degrading the question. I don't know the solution thats why I have put up question here. Same for all if everybody know the solution, then why this forum would run?

Whats logic behind degrade this question?

Comment: I believe it's because your logic is confusing. It is difficult to figure out exactly what you mean. For example, what is "this.n.this"? Use more real examples, with commit numbers and so on so that people can follow the train of events. That, and I'm sure it is difficult but because your English is not so good it makes it harder to understand. But that is not usually a problem. In this case it makes your logic that much harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I misunderstood your situation, but provided you remember correctly sha of the lost commit:

```
 git checkout a6dd3dd
 git checkout -b lost_head
```

And then fast-forward to master as any other temporary branch, e.g

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only lost_head
git branch -d lost_head
git push origin master
```